# How to get a list of pull request that have been merged into the master?

Tags: github

I was just going through the code on hexo.js a nodejs blogging platform and i wanted to know if there is any way in which i can see all the latest commits to the repo ( I.E. pull request that have been merged into the `master` repo ).

Ofcourse i can see the latest commit like so:

[image: latest commit]

But what if i want to see the last 10 commits that have been merged into the master ? How do i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the **2,658 commits** link (top left in your picture).

[image]

This takes you to the history, where you can select the branch whose history you can review (master should be the default).

[image]